# F() objects in mongoengine similar to that in django

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

Do we have something similar to  F() objects in mongoengine, similar to that in Django.

If yes then please help me in how to use it.

If No then please suggest a way to incorporate similar functionality in mongoengine.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `where` operator ( since v0.5 ):

```
User.objects( ).where( "this.firstname == this.lastname" )
```

Note that this is inefficient, since Mongo will not use indexes with these queries and thus it should be avoided:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_where

Comment: true, but as F objects works on the latest value is in db. The one which you are suggesting is simple filter and currently I am also doing something similar. Retrieving the value and doing the operations.

Comment: @Somesh Well, `where` is as efficient as you can get with Mongo ( when it comes to querying ). You can also try converting your collection to a simplier one with map/reduce and do an efficient query on the result. Except for that there is not much you can do.