# Mongoengine Query To Compare one Field to another

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongodb-query, mongoengine

```
class News(Document):
    news_id = IntField()
    post_date = DatetimeField()
    last_modified = DatetimeField()
```

This is Document

I want to make mongoengine query where last_modified is greater than post_date

Something like

News.objects(last_modified__gte = post_date)    `#mongoengine query`

Is there any way to make this type of query?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for mongo engine? http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#query-operators

Comment: Try with `News.objects(last_modified__gte = F('post_date'))`

Comment: What is `F` here? it says F is not defined `NameError`

Comment: in order to use the django `F` operator do `from django.db.models import F`

Comment: @Pynchia can you please tell me what does `F` means in your comment

Comment: I'm using  `Flask`. Do you something similar in flask?

Comment: please see [the official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/) on the `F` operator

Comment: ahahahaha, altright, I thought you were using django. Then have a look at this [SO QA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119005/f-objects-in-mongoengine-similar-to-that-in-django)

Comment: Thanks @Pynchia, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

In django you would do this with `F`, but since `F` does not work with mongoengine use `where` method-

```
query = "this.{last_modified}>this.{post_date}"

db_fields = {
    'last_modified': News._fields['last_modified'],
    'post_date': News._fields['post_date']
}

results = News.objects.where(query.format(*db_fields))
```

According to mongoengine documentation, '$where' clause is automatically substituted

```
 def where(self, where_clause):
 """Filter ``QuerySet`` results with a ``$where`` clause (a Javascript
    expression). Performs automatic field name substitution like
    :meth:`mongoengine.queryset.Queryset.exec_js`.

    .. note:: When using this mode of query, the database will call your
              function, or evaluate your predicate clause, for each object
              in the collection.

    .. versionadded:: 0.5
    """
```

**OR**

You could query mongodb directly -

```
query = "this.{last_modified}>this.{post_date}"

db_fields = {
    'last_modified': News._fields['last_modified'],
    'post_date': News._fields['post_date']
}

collection = News._get_collection()

results = list(collection.find({"$where": query.format(*db_fields)}))
```

Note:- You shouldn't hardcode db_fields name in your mongo queries.

Comment: Since `$where` uses JavaScript directly on the server then the fields should be specified in JavaScript notation only. If you got the notation right then this should be correct. The question is misleading from the use of an "equal" operator when they ask "greater than".

Comment: I have changed my answer, please see if this one suits you

Comment: Drop the interpolation as it is not needed ie. `"$where": "this.last_modified > this.post_date"`. No need for the python trickery. It's JavaScript. But I also voted since the principle is basically correct. However trying to replace the string values would make it fail.

Comment: Oops my bad again, I hope its fine now finally

Comment: Nope you made it worse. Read what I said. The query interpets objects as viewed by the JavaScript engine. There is no interplay with python at all once sent to the server. I actually gave you the correct syntax.

Comment: Since Mongoengine is providing abstraction and cleaner approach, why do you think I should use javascript syntax

Comment: Because that is what a `$where` query is, it uses JavaScript. Once you do that then mongoengine has nothing to do with it. There is no way for anything else than a `$where` clause to compare values of two fields in a document ( save the aggregation framework or mapReduce of course ). MongoEngine `.where()` is not the same thing. You just managed to talk yourself out of a basically correct answer into completely incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90527/discussion-between-hspandher-and-blakes-seven).

Comment: Nope it does not work at all, but your testing is incorrect. You are interpolating two values in a sample that happen to be the same. Create a new object that has different values ( but the same as each other ) and you will watch it fail to match the second object. Python code has nothing to do with this. I thought you had it basically correct at the start except for that misconception. But since you do not understand why it is wrong then that is why I retract my vote. Which was also in light of that I thought you were unfairly downvoted when on the right track. Clearly you are not though.